# SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed rendering at wrong resolution

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I just started with SpriteKit and unfortunately already got stuck with the first attemps. When creating sprites with any method that uses the name, they are not rendered at the right resolution, but roughly about factor 1.3 smaller. I'm loading an image that should fill the iphone 5 screen enirely:

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"1"];

sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                             CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
[self addChild:sprite];
```

Weirdly, the CGSize property is correct. My image file is named 1@2x.png, I have tried different names without success. I only noticed when I started working with a texture atlas, where the problem is the same.

Comment: check scene.scaleMode

Comment: the scaleMode pointed me to the right direction, because I'm using the Xcode template my scene is loaded from the sks file. When I change its dimension, the look change. How can I set up my scene with the device's native resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, currently that image won't necessarily be displayed on the whole screen. You've positioned it in the center with the `CGPointMake`, but you have to use  `[sprite setScale:]` to actually enlarge/shrink it. By including @2x at the end of the image name, you are saying that if there was a retina display, you want to substitute a better quality image for your standard one. That doesn't mean that visually the size will be different (because the retina one will use the 2x one, while the normal display will use the 1x one). Remember that retina have physically more pixels in a smaller area.

If you want to make the image take up the whole screen, you could try to set the size of the sprite to the size of the scene.